# Error during VAT Number verification

Tags: magento2, php, tax-calculation, vat-id

I have Magento 2.3.6 Instance on my local machine (Vagrant) now i am trying to add the merchant information in magento admin and validating the VAT ID for my merchant, but when i added it is saying "Error during VAT Number verification."

I have already checked the PHP-SOAP is enabled  and also tried the following solutions as well
[Zero tax for those with valid VAT Number (maybe via customer groups)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163779/zero-tax-for-those-with-valid-vat-number-maybe-via-customer-groups)

But still not validating the VAT it and thats why ZERO tax is not calculating for the customers.

Can anyone help in this regards, either is due to the LOCAL machine or something else i am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The built in validator refers to this endpoint

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/fbfac3e51730abe2b79c6072544bc9742fcf7606/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Vat.php#L47

```
https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl
```

Can you curl to this okay? Try over port 80 and 443 if you can

Answer (score 1):

Issue in my case was,

- VAT is charged if the merchant and customer are located in the same
  EU country.
- VAT is not charged if the merchant and customer are
  located in different EU countries, and both parties are EU-registered
  business entities.
- Use Merchant VAT ID in Magento and Also After creation of the Custom Account I was missing validating the VAT in customer account once that done it is working fine.

Hope it will help someone else.